# WordPress share settings into javascript file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am making a WordPress plugin and some of the options from the admin interface are for the JavaScript file that handles the interface of the widget.

The issue is that I do not see a practical way to echo the settings into that file. I was considering making a PHP file that fakes its file content type. Or creating a dynamic JavaScript file whenever the page loads, but currently im sharing the options through a hidden div that has the information as a base64 encoded json string that is read and loaded when the page finishes loading.

What is the best way to set my WordPress settings into my JavaScript file?

Comment: why not using localStorage? You can put the data you are now inserting the hidden div and use key/val of localStorage to save it. Then, each time the page is loaded you can check if the info is there and read it.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff the settings into an array, then use json_encode() to turn them into a JS array structure:

somescript.php:

```
<?php

$settings = array(
   'x' => 'foo',
   'y' => 'bar'
);

header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo 'var settings = ' . json_encode($settings);
```

Then load that up in your client html:

```
<script src="somescript.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have already considered this option as you can read by my post, but I need more information as to why this method would be better as opposed to other methods.